# Nicer expression for 2.1369288...?

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

In [Drift Analysis and Evolutionary Algorithms Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03226) by Johannes Lengler and Angelika Steger in Theorem 10, there is mention of a constant "$2.2$", and in the proof it becomes apparent that the theorem is actually true for all c, which are the solution to the following system:
Define $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$f(a, c) := ac  - e^{(a - 1)c} + \frac{a}{a - 1}$$
and consider the system of equations
\begin{align}f(a, c) &= 0\\\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a, c) &=0\end{align}

We are looking for a solution of this system near $(0.237, 2.13)$. It is easy to calculate solutions to this system numerically to arbitrary precision:
[Here is some code](https://gist.github.com/mo271/2331075d9e53aed26a55f758a398e4a9) to get $$c = 2.13692884344059837908651709517671705999047797307894493...$$

For $0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a, c) - c\cdot f(a, c)$ the exponential terms cancel and we get the relation $$c = \frac{\sqrt{-4a + 1} - 1}{2(a^2 - a)} \label{Eq:star}\tag{$\star$}$$
Substituting this expression back in $f(a, c)$, gives a function $g\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$g(a) := f(a, \tfrac{\sqrt{-4a + 1} - 1}{2(a^2 - a)}).$$
One way of defining $c$ is to define $a$ as the root of $g$ (near $0.237$) and then use \eqref{Eq:star} to obtain $c$.

- Is there is a less implicit way of expressing $c$?
- Is $c$ related to some known other known constants?

Two observations:

1. It seems like $a$ is not so important here, in the sense that we can reparameterize $a$ and replace it by a function $z(b)$ (as long as $z$ is differntiable and goes through $0.237$ in the domain) and then have as the second equation the derivative with respect to $b$ instead of $a$. I played around with this a bit and for example $z(b):= \frac{1 -b^2}{4}$ then gives $c = \frac{8}{b^3 + b^2 + 3b + 3}$, but there might be an even better reparameterization.
2. Instead of expressing $c$ in terms of $a$ as the solution of a quadratic equation, one can also express $a$ in terms of $c$ as the solution of a cubic equation and then substitute back into $f$ to get a function only depending on $c$. Then the number I'm looking for is a root of that function, but this function is even more ugly than the description involving $a$.

Comment: fyi: this constant is not (yet) in the OEIS...

Comment: Nor is it in the version of the Inverse Symbolic Calculator available at https://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2.136928843440598379086517) also comes up empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) to @TheSimpliFire’s [equation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464355):

$$\frac{k}{(k-1)^2}+1=e^k\iff k=1+\sqrt{\frac k{e^k-1}}\\\implies k=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\frac x{e^x-1}\right)^\frac n2\right|_1$$

Now use the Norlund polynomial, or [generalized Bernoulli number](https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/53-4/MollVignat04222015.pdf), [generating function](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/NorlundB2/02/). One notices the $\frac1{(n-m+1)!}$ truncates the inner sum:

$$\boxed{c=\frac{k^3}{k^2-k+1},k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}\frac{B_n^{(\frac m2)}}{m! (n-m+1)!}}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=evaluate+c%3Dk%5E3.0%2F%28k%5E2-k%2B1%29%2Ck%3Dsum%5Bsum%5BNorlundB%5Bm%2Cn%2F2.0%5D%2F%28n%21+%28m-n%2B1%29%21%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C20%7D%5D)

Comment: Note: the $n$ and $m$ indices were switched at the end

Comment: @PeterTaylor What does the sum become then; it seems to [diverge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%281.0%2B√%28bernoulli%28n%29%29%29%5E%28n%2B1%29%2F%28n%2B1%29%21%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C20%7D%5D)? The closest formula for the inner sum was [this one](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/NorlundB2/23/01/0001/), but there is an extra $(-1)^k$ factor

Comment: Simple case of misunderstanding the notation: $B_n^{(\frac m2)} \neq \sqrt{B_n}^m$.

Comment: Are there any other formulas for $k$? The only other sum found was [fairly long](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2BSum%5BSum%5BSum%5B%28%28Binomial%5Bn+-+1%2C+m%5D+%281%2Fn%21%29%29+%28FactorialPower%5Bn%2F2.0%2C+n+-+1+-+m%5D+Binomial%5B-n%2F2%2C+k%5D+%28-1%29%5Ek%29+%28k+%2B+n%2F2%29%5Em+%28-1%29%5Em%29%2FE%5E%28k+%2B+n%2F2%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+100%7D%5D%2C+%7Bm%2C+0%2C+10%7D%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C1%2C+10%7D%5D). Maybe there is an integral representation too.

Answer (score 12):

With a few substitutions, we find that $$c=\frac{k^3}{k^2-k+1}\quad\text{where}\quad1+\frac k{(1-k)^2}=e^k.$$ The solution for $k$ requires a more advanced function than Lambert $W$.

Comment: Nice! That is already much shorter!